# Getting data from an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I get an array of hashes from a google sheet, it looks like this

```
itemList = [ {:id => '1', :type => 'A', :category => 'Cat1' }, 
             {:id => '2', :type => 'A', :category => 'Cat1' },
             {:id => '3', :type => 'B', :category => 'Cat1' },
             {:id => '4', :type => 'B', :category => 'Cat1' },
             {:id => '1', :type => 'A', :category => 'Cat2' },
             {:id => '2', :type => 'A', :category => 'Cat2' },
             {:id => '3', :type => 'C', :category => 'Cat2' } ]
```

I would like to be able to print this on the terminal

```
Cat1
A
1, 2
B
3, 4

Cat2
A
1, 2
C
3
```

Is there an easy way to do it?
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I using itemList.each, prevCategory, prevType. I did not like the code, because I was not using the power of ruby.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will provide you required format,

```
items = itemList.group_by {|x| x[:category] }

val = items.inject({}) do |m,(k,v)|
    tmp = v.group_by { |x| x[:type] }
    m[k] = tmp.update(tmp) { |i,j| j.map { |x| x[:id] } }
    m
end

# => {"Cat1"=>{"A"=>["1", "2"], "B"=>["3", "4"]}, "Cat2"=>{"A"=>["1", "2"], "C"=>["3"]}}
```

Display it like below,

```
 val.each { |k,v| puts k; v.each { |i,j| puts i; puts j.join(', ') }; puts }

Cat1
A
1, 2
B
3, 4

Cat2
A
1, 2
C
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I wanted.